# Are there any interesting pgm map files available for simulation?

Tags: navigation, mapping, turtlebot, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am looking for some interesting .pgm (and related yaml) map files to use in simulation in player stage, with a turtlebot.  I have found a set of willow garage maps here:
http://pr.willowgarage.com/data/maps/

Also, I found one called MIT infinite corridor.  Are there any other available maps of large, interesting environments that can be used in simulation experiments?  Places such as museums, airports or malls, for instance?

I realize that there may be limitations on map size and memory, but I want to see what maps are out there for research use.  Also, if there are any known environments that are commonly used as testbeds, that would be great.

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37762/are-there-any-interesting-pgm-map-files-available-for-simulation?/) by [ceverett](https://answers.ros.org/users/1761/ceverett/) on ROS Answers with karma: 332 on 2012-07-02

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I've been researching relations between map size and memory usage and there is definitely a limitation.
Im using the AMCL particle filter to localize a robot in a map. I'm not sure how AMCL handles the map information or if its even the right process to look at but I can see a clear tendency while trying with different map sizes.

I got something like this:
Free memory (total 8GB) AMCL    map_server Mapsize
1,98GB                  1231MB  524MB      292MB
4,50GB                  446MB   118MB      26MB
4,87GB                  142MB   0,075MB    3,1MB

the 292MB-map is the same map as the 26MB but with bigger canvas size (lots of gray empty space outside the map).

I can give you the map I used if you got some place to upload it to. Its recorded in a mall but its a lot of galss of which the laser doesn't reflect on, so the map is a bit messy.

I hope this can be useful for you!
Please share if you come to any more conclusions!

---

Originally posted by [Niclas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2795/niclas/) with karma: 16 on 2012-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ceverett](https://answers.ros.org/users/1761/ceverett/) on 2012-07-20**:
Thanks for your comment.  I would like to see your map if it is not trouble, you can use wetransfer.com to email it to me, to pippin AT gatech.edu  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just to add something useful to this old thread:

Here's another 2D map:
**willow-2010-02-18-0.10.pgm**
Available here:
https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_apps/tree/indigo/turtlebot_navigation/maps

[image: image description]

"**FR079**" 2D map and 3D world model:
[http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/~lau/dynamicvoronoi/FR079.png](http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/%7Elau/dynamicvoronoi/FR079.png)
http://ais.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/projects/datasets/octomap/

**2D maps only:**
[http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/~lau/dynamicvoronoi/FR101.png](http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/%7Elau/dynamicvoronoi/FR101.png)
[http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/~lau/dynamicvoronoi/Factory.png](http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/%7Elau/dynamicvoronoi/Factory.png)

**Lots more 2D maps** in the USC Radish repository:
http://cres.usc.edu/radishrepository/view-all.php

---

Originally posted by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) with karma: 1103 on 2017-01-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4